# Accessing context.xml Environment variable from any JSP file

Tags: jsp, tomcat

I have items like:
    Environment name="debug" value="true type="java.lang.String" override="false"
in my context.xml file in dev

In non-development environments I don't have this line.

In my webapp's JSP files I would like to be able to read this value and do something depending on whether it is set or not:

e.g. JSP:
    if test="${debug eq "true"}"...do something ...

Answer (score 2):

You need to use this code to access the value :

```
InitialContext initialContext = new javax.naming.InitialContext();  
String debug = (String) initialContext.lookup("java:comp/env/debug");
```

Encapsulate it in a custom tag to access it from JSP.

Comment: any way to do this w/out a custom tag? maybe using a Spring bean?

Comment: You could also wrap in an application scoped bean which does that in the constructor, yes.